# LaTeX algorithm2e vlined parameter doesn't work

Tags: latex, algorithm2e

I've been trying to set a short LaTeX doc with an algorithm. The vertical block lines should have a horizontal line marking the end, like in this picture from the handbook:
[image]

But I get this result instead:
[image: current result despite vlined]

No idea what I'm doing wrong. The whole doc for the setup is as following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered,ruled,noend]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
     \NoCaptionOfAlgo
     \begin{algorithm}
     \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
     \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

     \If{true}
     {
         test
     }
     \caption{test}
     \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `noend` you explicitly remove the horizontal end lines

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[vlined,linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
     \NoCaptionOfAlgo
     \begin{algorithm}
     \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
     \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}

     \If{true}
     {
         test
     }
     \caption{test}
     \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]